# How to deploy to CloudBees PaaS in EU with Maven plugin

Tags: cloudbees

When using the CloudBees SDK, I can use the parameter "-ep eu" to deploy to EU data center, but how can this be done with the Maven plugin? -ep is reserved to encrypting server password in Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set property bees.apiurl or plugin parameter  to https://api-eu.cloudbees.com/api

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a way I could have found that from the documentation? Or is it not documented? I looked for articles about deploying to Europe, but couldn't find anything that used maven.